# ADC on PIC32MX575F512H

Tags: pic, adc

I'm trying to adapt the actual circuitry below in order to get the current consumption that comes from the VCC_12

[image]

My question is:

1) What value and tolerance should I use for Rsense?

Comment: No that's not going to work either. You'll be feeding 12V into your PIC's ADC1 & ADC2 inputs and the smoke will escape shortly thereafter. You need a voltage divider from each side of Rsense and feed the output of that to your PIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to measure the current of your circuit, essentially all of the rest of your circuitry should be powered off of the junction you labeled ADC2.  That should now be your new VCC.

You haven't said what you maximum current will be.  That is needed in order to pick a reasonable sense resistor.

For example, if your are going to be drawing 1 A, then the resistor should be very small, say 0.1 Ω, 1% such as this one [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/RU1608FR100CS/1276-6155-1-ND/3969127) so the drop across the resistor is not more than 100 mV.  Since this resistor is 1/4W, that should be good up to an amp or so, if your circuit draws more than 12v 1A, look for a bigger wattage resistor.

But if the maximum current is 200 mA, then you can get by on a 0.5 Ω, 1% such as this one [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CSR0805FKR500/CSR0805FKR500CT-ND/2217488).  Again the 1/4W will be fine.  I'll assume this resistor value in the rest of my answer.

There are two ways to measure the voltage across the resistor.  One way is to use a current sense amplifier, as Matt Young suggests in his answer.  That adds an IC and some expense, but only requires one ADC input and will be very accurate.

The other is to use two ADC inputs, one across each end of the 0.5 Ω resistor.  Since 12V is way higher than the 3.3V limit of your ADC, you will need a voltage divider as you already surmised.

For each divider, if you use a top value of 75K, and a bottom value of 25K, that will cut the voltage by 3/4 (i.e. 12V looks like 3V).

[image]

Measure the top both ends of the resistor with the ADC.  Convert to volts.  Divide by 0.5 (the value of the resistor) and you will have the current.

Note: this will be usable only down to a little below 10 mA or so, because of the resolution of your ADC.  The ADC on the PIC32 is 10-bit.  Assuming the ADC reference voltage is 3.3V, then each bit of the ADC = 3.3 / 1024 = 0.00322V or 3.22 mV.

The voltage across the resistor will be 500 mV / A since the resistor is 0.5 Ω.  So for 100 mA of current, the voltage difference will be 50 mV, or the difference in counts between the two ends of the resistor will only be about 15.

You can increase the resolution by making the resistor bigger (i.e. doubling it from 0.5 Ω to 1 Ω), but this will also proportionally increase the voltage drop.  200 mA with 0.5 Ω => 100 mV drop, whereas 200 mA across 1 Ω = 200 mV drop across the resistor.

If you need better resolution than that, go with the current sense amplifier.  You could also with a higher value resistor; for example if you know your current won't be more than 100 mA, and you could use 1 Ω instead of 0.1 Ω and still only have a 100 mV voltage drop.  Now you will have 100 mV / 100 mA

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you're trying to adapt is for measuring the power rail voltage. The circuit you've drawn is pointless because you're measuring the current through that voltage divider, which will never change. \$R_{sense}\$ needs to be right after the 12V regulator, and be sufficiently small to not dissipate a bunch of power or drop a bunch of voltage. You need to make that call based on your expected current draw. Generally you'll want it to be small, probably less than \$1\Omega\$, and put it into a current sense amplifier, like a [MAX4732](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4372-MAX4372T.pdf). The output of that amplifier can go into your ADC.

Comment: For my case I have two voltage regulators that comes from my VCC_12V. One from 12V to 3.3V and another from 12V to 5.V. It doesn't make sense for me but it was what I got from the previous schematic and I'm trying to read the current consumption by the easiest way without making a new PCB.